# JOGL FPS Issues with glDrawArrays

Tags: java, performance, opengl, frame-rate, jogl

I have been trying to make some 3d stuff with JOGL.

When rendering 2 2d boxes in the 3d plane FPS can drop to under 15

when I move the camera closer. I don't know exactly what is taking down the performance so much.

```
    float camX = (float) Main.cameraX;
    float camY = (float) Main.cameraY;
    float camZ = (float) Main.cameraZ;
    float camRotX = (float) Main.cameraRotX;
    float camRotY = (float) Main.cameraRotY;
    float camRotZ = (float) Main.cameraRotZ;

    gl.glRotatef(camRotX, 1, 0, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(camRotY, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(camRotZ, 0, 0, 1);

    gl.glTranslatef(x - camX, y - camY, z - camZ);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, 0, verticesBuffer);

    gl.glEnableClientState(GL2.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertices.length / 3);

    gl.glTranslatef(-x + camX, -y + camY, -z + camZ);

    gl.glRotatef(-camRotZ, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glRotatef(-camRotY, 0, 1, 0);
    gl.glRotatef(-camRotX, 1, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Using all this deprecated stuff will certainly not help performance, but for drawing 2 2D "boxes" that shouldn't matter at all. Maybe you're using a software renderer?

Comment: Please post a SSCCE if you really want to get some help. Do you reproduce your problem with this example? https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Rudimentary_standalone_example_using_the_fixed_pipeline_by_Julien_Gouesse